# SQL Aggregate Query - Count Nulls

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, count, aggregate-functions

I've got a database setup where we have a list of jobs. Each job is at 1 to many locations. A user can apply for a job, at any location. They can apply separately to the same job at different locations. Each job application has 4 statuses as it progresses, from 1. New through to 4. Closed.

I need to run a SQL query to present a summary of every job, at every location, and for every status a count of the relevant applications. So for example

```
+ ---- + -------- + ------ + ----- +
| Job  | Location | Status | Count |
+ ---- + -------- + ------ + ----- +
| 1000 | 1        | 1      | 7     |
| 1000 | 1        | 2      | 0     |
| 1000 | 1        | 3      | 1     |
| 1000 | 1        | 4      | 1     |
| 1000 | 2        | 1      | 4     |
| 1000 | 2        | 2      | 2     |
| 1000 | 2        | 3      | 0     |
| 1000 | 2        | 4      | 8     |
+ ---- + -------- + ------ + ----- +
```

In addition I'm ideally looking to sum the 4 status counts together into a total sum in the same list.

This is the SQL statement I've written so far:-

```
SELECT B.JobID, B.LocationID, B.ApplicationStatusID, COUNT(B.JobID) AS CountOfResults
FROM Job AS A
JOIN JobApplication AS B ON A.JobID = B.JobID
LEFT JOIN JobApplicationStatus AS C ON B.ApplicationStatusID = C.JobApplicationStatusID
WHERE A.BrandID = 1
GROUP BY B.JobID, B.LocationID, B.ApplicationStatusID
```

It works, bar two things:-

- I'm unsure how to get the total count (or could I do this server side later)
- It's not showing results where the count is 0.

Could anyone advise on how to get 4 status for every job at every location, even if that is 0? I've seen various advise on other threads about a left join, but I've had no success yet.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit - Showing Job Table Example Data**

Assuming Job Locations is a table of addresses with ID numbers 5, 6 and 7.

```
Job
+ ------ + ---------- + ------------------- +
| Job ID | Job Title  | Description         |
+ ------ + ---------- + ------------------- +
| 1      | Developer  | My Nice Description |
| 2      | Full Stack | Another Description |
+ ------ + ---------- + ------------------- +

Job Location
+ -- + ------ + ----------- +
| ID | Job ID | Location ID |
+ -- + ------ + ----------- +
| 1  | 1      | 5           |
| 2  | 1      | 6           |
| 3  | 2      | 5           |
| 4  | 2      | 6           |
| 5  | 2      | 7           |
+ -- + ------ + ----------- +

Job Application
+ -- + ------- + ------ + ----------- + --------------------- +
| ID | User ID | Job ID | Location ID | Application Status ID |
+ -- + ------- + ------ + ----------- + --------------------- +
| 1  | 1       | 1      | 5           | 1                     |
| 2  | 1       | 1      | 6           | 2                     |
| 3  | 2       | 1      | 5           | 1                     |
| 4  | 2       | 2      | 7           | 4                     |
+ -- + ------- + ------ + ----------- + --------------------- +
```

In the job application status table:-

- User 1 applies for Job 1 at Location 5, and their application status is 1.
- User 1 also applies for Job 1 at Location 6, and their application status is 2.
- User 2 applies for Job 1 at Location 5 and their application status is 1.
- User 2 also applies for Job 2 at Location 7 and their application status is 4.

What I am looking for here, would be a query to return the following:-

```
Result
+ --- + -------- + ------ + ----- +
| Job | Location | Status | Count |
+ --- + -------- + ------ + ----- +
| 1   | 5        | 1      | 2     |
| 1   | 5        | 2      | 0     |
| 1   | 5        | 3      | 0     |
| 1   | 5        | 4      | 0     |
| 1   | 6        | 1      | 0     |
| 1   | 6        | 2      | 1     |
| 1   | 6        | 3      | 0     |
| 1   | 6        | 4      | 0     |
+ --- + -------- + ------ + ----- +
```

And so on, 0's should be displayed. And the count is the count of job applications in that status number. There are 4 status numbers, which are set in a joining table called JobApplicationStatus.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using? also please show the expected output.

Comment: Just updated to show the expected output above. SQL Server 2014.

Comment: where do you want to show the total sum?should that be a column?

Comment: You mean you get no count for Jobs with no JobApplication? Then use an outer join: `FROM Job AS A LEFT JOIN JobApplication`.

Comment: I was thinking that the total sum could be the same column as above, when grouping by NULL? I think I've seen that used before, but I'm not sure?

Comment: A side note: Meaningless alias names just confuse. Use meaningful abbreviations instead, e.g. `j` for `Job`, `a` or `ja` for JobApplication, etc.

Comment: show some sample data from the 3 tables involved.

Comment: @vkp - I have just added this for you above.

Comment: Thanks for formatting this guys, was unsure how to represent a table of data like this.

Comment: Sorry one thing I've come to notice when using this and apologies if I didn't document this in the original question. When there is a count of 0 for  all four status, all four rows are left off the results? I have 50 jobs each with 4 statuses so I would expect to see 200 rows? I see 160, and the remaining 40 are jobs where there are no job applications at all. Is this a second cross join to do this? Possibly with the location table?

Comment: There is a way to have job id that have no application. Just change the `JOIN JobApplication` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN JobApplication` and change `B.JobID` in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` clause with `A.JobID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. Since you want all status even if there is no correspondence in Job Application, you need to use a [`cross join`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx)

Also, in this case, since there will be a "link" for every status, you need to use SUM with a CASE scenario instead of COUNT.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44820/8)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Job
    ([JobID] int, [JobTitle] varchar(10), [Description] varchar(23), [BrandID] int)
;

INSERT INTO Job
    ([JobID], [JobTitle], [Description], [BrandID])
VALUES
    (1, 'Developer', 'My nice description', 1),
    (2, 'Full Stack', 'Another job description', 1)
;


CREATE TABLE JobApplication
    ([ID] int, [UserID] int, [JobID] int, [LocationID] int, [ApplicationStatusID] int)
;

INSERT INTO JobApplication
    ([ID], [UserID], [JobID], [LocationID], [ApplicationStatusID])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 5, 1),
    (2, 1, 1, 6, 2),
    (3, 2, 1, 5, 1),
    (4, 2, 2, 7, 4)
;


CREATE TABLE JobApplicationStatus
    ([JobApplicationStatusID] int, [Description] varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO JobApplicationStatus
    ([JobApplicationStatusID], [Description])
VALUES
    (1, 'New'),
    (2, 'In Progress'),
    (3, 'Hold'),
    (4, 'Closed')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT B.JobID, B.LocationID, C.JobApplicationStatusID, 
sum(case when B.ApplicationStatusID = C.JobApplicationStatusID then 1 else 0 end) AS CountOfResults
FROM Job AS A
JOIN JobApplication AS B ON A.JobID = B.JobID
cross join JobApplicationStatus AS C
WHERE A.BrandID = 1
GROUP BY B.JobID, B.LocationID, C.JobApplicationStatusID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44820/8/0)**:

```
| JobID | LocationID | JobApplicationStatusID | CountOfResults |
|-------|------------|------------------------|----------------|
|     1 |          5 |                      1 |              2 |
|     1 |          5 |                      2 |              0 |
|     1 |          5 |                      3 |              0 |
|     1 |          5 |                      4 |              0 |
|     1 |          6 |                      1 |              0 |
|     1 |          6 |                      2 |              1 |
|     1 |          6 |                      3 |              0 |
|     1 |          6 |                      4 |              0 |
|     2 |          7 |                      1 |              0 |
|     2 |          7 |                      2 |              0 |
|     2 |          7 |                      3 |              0 |
|     2 |          7 |                      4 |              1 |
```

**EDITED :**

There is a way to have job id that have no application. Just change the `JOIN JobApplication` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN JobApplication` and change `B.JobID` in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` clause with `A.JobID`

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem typically involves a `cross join` and then some way to bring in the results (`left join`/`group by`) or subquery.  This suggests:

```
SELECT j.JobID, l.LocationID, ja.ApplicationStatusID,
       COUNT(ja.JobID) AS CountOfResults
FROM Job j CROSS JOIN
     Location l LEFT JOIN
     JobApplication ja
     ON j.JobID = jb.JobID AND
        l.LocationId = jb.LocationId
WHERE j.BrandID = 1
GROUP BY j.JobID, l.LocationID, ja.ApplicationStatusID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same results without the case by using count.  I came up with almost the exact solution as Fabien.  The cross join is key here.

**Setup:**

```
DECLARE @Job TABLE(
        JobId tinyint,
        JobTitle varchar(55),
        JobDescription varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO @Job 
    VALUES 
    (1,'Developer','My nice description'), 
    (2,'Full Stack','Another job description');

DECLARE @JobLocation TABLE(
    Id tinyint,
    JobId tinyint,
    LocationId tinyint

);

INSERT INTO @JobLocation 
    VALUES 
    (1,1,5), 
    (2,1,6),
    (3,2,5),
    (4,2,6),
    (5,2,7);

DECLARE @JobApplication TABLE(
    Id tinyint,
    UserId tinyint,
    JobId tinyint,
    LocationId tinyint,
    ApplicationStatusId tinyint
);

INSERT INTO @JobApplication
    VALUES
    (1,1,1,5,1),
    (2,1,1,6,2),
    (3,2,1,5,1),
    (4,2,2,7,4);
--End sample data

DECLARE @JobStatus TABLE(
    StatusId int,
    ApplicationStatus varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO @JobStatus
    VALUES
    (1, 'Application Received'),
    (2, 'Application Review Started'),
    (3, 'Application In Final Review'),
    (4, 'Application Closed');
```

**Query:**

```
select job.JobId,
       jl.LocationId,
       js.StatusId,
       count(ja.Id) as StatusCount

from @Job job
    cross apply @JobStatus js 
    inner join @JobLocation jl on job.JobId = jl.JobId
    left join @JobApplication ja on job.JobId = ja.JobId 
        and ja.LocationId = jl.LocationId 
        and ja.ApplicationStatusId = js.StatusId
where job.JobId = 1 -- filter for single job
group by job.jobId, jl.LocationId, js.StatusId
order by job.JobId, jl.LocationId, js.StatusId
```

Answer (score 0):

Fabien's answer is good, and you should mark that one as the answer. But I just wanted to add that you could get the total sums that you want by using a common table expression and a correlated subquery with his query

```
; with 
    StatusCounts as (
        SELECT  B.JobID, B.LocationID, C.JobApplicationStatusID, 
                sum(case when B.ApplicationStatusID = C.JobApplicationStatusID then 1 else 0 end) AS CountOfResults
            FROM Job AS A
            JOIN JobApplication AS B ON A.JobID = B.JobID
            cross join JobApplicationStatus AS C
            WHERE A.BrandID = 1
            GROUP BY B.JobID, B.LocationID, C.JobApplicationStatusID
    )
select  *,
        (select SUM(CountOfResults)
            from StatusCounts SQ
            where SQ.JobID = D.JobID
                and SQ.LocationID = D.LocationID
        ) as TotalSum
    from StatusCounts D
```